# Как спрятать IP-адреса пользователей Linux от других пользователей?

Tags: linux, ip

Вообще-то айпишники это секрет, но дефолтные конфигуации дебиана и убунты светят их всем подряд:

```
$ lastlog | grep -v Never
Username         Port     From              Latest
root             pts/0    94.29.***.***     Mon Jan 28 07:59:37 +0000 2019
adm1me           pts/7    98.***.***.33     Sun Jul  2 13:49:34 +0000 2017
admin            pts/1    cpe-70-***-***-22 Sun Mar 20 18:28:16 +0000 2016
adm1ru           pts/0    ***.***.191.116   Sun Nov 29 19:52:10 +0000 2015
mc123val         pts/0    176.***.***.100   Sat Sep 22 19:04:16 +0000 2018
# ... и ещё десятки строчек на среднестатистическом shared-хостинге
```

Это неприемлемо.

Пробовал сделать `sudo chmod o-rwx /var/log/wtmp /var/log/lastlog /var/run/utmp`, но после перезагрузки права на чтение возвращаются на место.

Comment: при старте системы эти файлы выправляются. на случай если они повреждены. найдите загрузочный скрипт, который это делает и попробуйте поменять там. лучше конечно на машине с прямым доступом к меню загрузчика, что бы в случае если после этого система перестанет пускать даже рута можно было сделать init=/bin/bash

Comment: может создавать пользователей с флагом `--no-log-init`

Comment: @VTT а вот log я как раз вполне хочу, чтоб читать рутом (но только рутом)

Comment: А? Секрет?! Откуда это?